# Can't create annotated tag with gitlab api v4

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I'm trying to create annotated tag with [POST /tags/](https://docs.gitlab.com/14.1/ee/api/tags.html#create-a-new-tag)

The tag appears without it, even with hardcode **param** (snippet below).

```
script:
    - git tag ${TAG} || true
    - git push origin ${TAG}
    - '#curl -X POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${CI_TAG_TOKEN}" "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags?tag_name=${TAG}&ref=master&message=testtag" '
```

I suppose that the problem may happens cause I do not specify the message in the git tag -m, but if I try to do this, an error occurs:

> Cannot autodetect email

Which is probably reasonable for the runner command.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is there an error when you try to create the tag via API and not using `git`?

Answer (score 0):

That should be easier to go with [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#create-annotated-tags-with-the-releases-api) (June 2022)

> ### Create annotated tags with the Releases API
>
> Previously, you were only able to create lightweight tags when using the Releases API to create a release.
>
> With this update, you can now add an optional `tag_message` parameter to create an annotated tag when creating a release.
> This enables you to include relevant information along with the new tag, so downstream users and applications can have additional context.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/#create-a-release) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/268018).

That is confirmed with [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#create-annotated-tags-using-the-release-cli) (August 2022):

> ### Create annotated tags using the Release CLI
>
> Previously, you were only able to create lightweight tags when using the GitLab Release CLI to create a release.
>
> With this update, you can now add an optional `tag-message` parameter to create an annotated tag when creating a release.
> This enables you to include relevant information along with the new tag so downstream users and application can have additional context.
>
> See [Documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/tree/master/docs#create-a-new-release) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/issues/62).
>
> ```
> release-cli --server-url https://gitlab.com --job-token=SOME_JOB_TOKEN --project-id 12345 create help
> ```

---

Other approach, with [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#create-annotated-tags-by-using-releasetagmessage-keyword) (August 2022):

> ### Create annotated tags by using `release:tag_message` keyword
>
> Create annotated tags by using `release:tag_message` keyword
>
> You can now create an annotated tag when you create a release.
> In the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file, use the `release` keyword to include an optional `tag_message` subkey and specify a message.
> This enables you to include relevant information along with the new tag, so downstream users and applications can have additional context.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#releasetag_message) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363024).

---

With [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#create-annotated-tags-in-the-releases-page) (October 2022):

> ### Create annotated tags in the Releases page
>
> You can now create annotated tags and add them to your releases in the Releases page. You can use annotated tags to provide downstream users and applications with additional information about a release.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_5/release-create-annotated-tag.png -- Create annotated tags in the Releases page]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#create-a-release-in-the-releases-page) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/362481).